# How do I receive push notifications for all posts in a Facebook group?

Tags: facebook, push-notifications

I used to be able to receive push notifications for all postings to a specific Facebook group, but that option no longer appears anymore.

Here is the current Facebook setting:

[image: Settings Screenshot]

How do I receive push notifications for all posts in a Facebook group again?